# How to partition an oracle table by a date column?

Tags: database, oracle, date, database-partitioning, database-scripts

I have a table in oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE transaction (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    accountnumber VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    stmtvaluedate DATE NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

And I want to partition this table by the stmtvaluedate column. My goal is to create a new partition after a month have passed.

Is there any good script, for it? Or I have to create static numbers of partitions?

The best would be: if a month have passed, a new partition will be created automatically.

Can anyone give me an example about how to partition a table by a date column after every month? If the automatically partitioning is impossible, than I would need an example, which creates partitions to a year from now by a date column, about every month.

Thanks!

Comment: [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/part_admin001.htm#BAJHFFBE) could helps. You can use Interval-Partitioned Table. But it works only for Oracle 11.1 and upper

Comment: Thank you. And can I partition by **week** or **day** too?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you want to do is completely possible.  This should do it:

```
CREATE TABLE transaction (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    accountnumber VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    stmtvaluedate DATE NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (stmtvaluedate)
INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL (1,'MONTH')) 
    ( partition transaction_old values less than (to_date('01-JAN-2000','DD-MON-YYYY') ));
```

Comment: And what if I want to partition a table not by mounth, but by a week, or a day? Are these rigth?: 
**INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL (1,'WEEK'))** 
or 
**INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL (1,'DAY'))**

And what will clause the date 01-JAN-2000? Does it mean, if a *stmtvaluedate* value is less than 2000.01.01, than that row will go into the partition?

Comment: Use `NUMTODSINTERVAL` for days and weeks.  And yes, the 1/1/2000 clause is to tell Oracle to put all the data before a given date into a single partition.  If you have a lot of historical data, that date may not be appropriate.